# How to draw a semi-ellipse in react native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Recently I tried a lot to draw a semi-ellipse in react native but I didn't get any good result. Here is what I tried

```
semiEllipse:{
        width: '100%',
        height: 50,
        borderRadius: 0.7*width,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'red',

      }
```

The above code gives me the following output:
[image]

but this is not what I am trying to achieve as you guys can see this is not a pure ellipse.

What I am trying to achieve is half of the following:
[image]

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
width: 100,
height: 100,
backgroundColor: 'red',
borderRadius: 50,
transform: [
  {scaleX: 2}
]
```

This should give you an oval shape. I would then just do a minus margin and overflow:hidden on the parent.